# Receive push notifications for closed app

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, urbanairship.com

I have successfully implemented push notifications via "Urban Airship" to my app. But I only receive the notifications if my app is opened or minimized. How can I make the app receive these notifications even when it's not running?
Here's the code I used to make UA running:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(){
           AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);
           UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
           PushManager.enablePush();
           String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
           String model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
           String ver = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
           Logger.info("My Application onCreate - App APID: " + apid);
           Logger.info("My Application onCreate - MOBILE NAME: " + model);
           Logger.info("My Application onCreate - EMAIL IS: " + getUsername());
           Logger.info("My Application onCreate - ANDROID VERSION: " + ver);
           PushManager.shared().setAlias(getUsername() + "-" + model + "-" + ver);

           PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to implement a service to stay listening all the time independently of the apps state.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: yeah i'm doing my research, but I lack experience, some are saying it should just work because Google Cloud Messaging is enabled.